# ElasticSearch.NET NEST search<T> url

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

My correct index path is `POST: /foo/_search` but below code hits `POST: /foo/bar/_search`.

```
var node = new Uri("http://elasticsearch-server.com:9200");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
settings.DefaultIndex("foo");
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
var response = client.Search<Bar>(s => s
.Query(q => q.Term(o => o.userName, "test"))
);

// POCO for response fields
public class Bar
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdTime { get; set; }
}
```

Above code `response` returns below message;

> Valid NEST response built from a successful low level call on POST: /foo/bar/_search

How can I set search path correctly?

**Trial 1**

When I omitted `settings.DefaultIndex("foo");` line, it throws `ArgumentException` as below, but when I set `DefaultIndex()`, `Search<T>` uses `T` name as a second path.

> ArgumentException: Index name is null for the given type and no default index is set. Map an index name using ConnectionSettings.MapDefaultTypeIndices() or set a default index using ConnectionSettings.DefaultIndex().

**Trial 2**
Refer to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/index-name-inference.html#_mapping_an_index_name_for_pocos_2),

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node)
.MapDefaultTypeIndices(m => m.Add(typeof(Bar), "foo"));
```

Above code returns same result in response.

> Valid NEST response built from a successful low level call on POST: /foo/bar/_search

Comment: I have the same code and it works well. could you try this snippet of the code: var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://elasticsearch-server.com:9200")).DefaultIndex("foo");var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

Comment: @Soren // Thanks for your comment. Hmm... still has same issue. It uses POCO name as a second path. I need to investigate more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A large proportion of the Elasticsearch API exposed through NEST is in a strongly typed fashion, including `.Search<T>()`; with this endpoint, both `"index"` and `"type"` will be inferred from `T`, but sometimes you might want to set a different value to that which is inferred. In these cases, you can call additional methods on the search fluent API (or search object, if using the object initializer syntax) to override the inferred values

```cs
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
            .DefaultIndex("foo");

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    // POST http://localhost:9200/foo/bar/_search
    // Will try to deserialize all _source to instances of Bar
    client.Search<Bar>(s => s
        .MatchAll()
    );

    // POST http://localhost:9200/foo/_search
    // Will try to deserialize all _source to instances of Bar
    client.Search<Bar>(s => s
        .AllTypes()
        .MatchAll()
    );

    // POST http://localhost:9200/_search
    // Will try to deserialize all _source to instances of Bar
    client.Search<Bar>(s => s
        .AllTypes()
        .AllIndices()
        .MatchAll()
    );

    connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
            .InferMappingFor<Bar>(m => m
                .IndexName("bars")
                .TypeName("barbar")
            );

    client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    // POST http://localhost:9200/bars/barbar/_search
    // Will try to deserialize all _source to instances of Bar
    client.Search<Bar>(s => s
        .MatchAll()
    );

    // POST http://localhost:9200/bars/_search
    // Will try to deserialize all _source to instances of Bar
    client.Search<Bar>(s => s
        .AllTypes()
        .MatchAll()
    );

    // POST http://localhost:9200/_all/barbar/_search
    // Will try to deserialize all _source to instances of Bar
    client.Search<Bar>(s => s
        .AllIndices()
        .MatchAll()
    );

    // POST http://localhost:9200/_search
    // Will try to deserialize all _source to instances of Bar
    client.Search<Bar>(s => s
        .AllIndices()
        .AllTypes()
        .MatchAll()
    );
}


public class Bar
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdTime { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You may add **other parameters** in your search lambda expression `var response = client.Search<Bar>(s => s.Index("indexName").Query(q => q.Term(o => o.userName, "test")));`

Comment: Hmm...either `Index("indexName")` or `DefaultIndex("indexName")` gives identical path.

Comment: `.DefaultIndex("defaultIndex")` will be used if no index name is specified in the request, and no index name is set to be inferred for a given type `T`. See Index Name Inference for more details: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/index-name-inference.html

Answer (score 0):

I was newbie in ElasticSearch and didn't know about `_type`.

I set identical `_type` name to POCO class name, and it works as I expected. 
So we can say, `{index}/{type}` is what path expression is.